# Win7: High System process memory usage

Tags: windows-7, memory

I noticed recently on my Win7 x64 that the "System" process gradually increases its process private memory usage. Immediate after boot it starts small (<50 MB) and gradually increases over time to as high as 6 GB. I've restarted the computer a few times now and this happens across boots.

Is this typically indicative of a memory leak in some driver? What would be the best way to diagnose this?

I don't recall seeing this more than a few weeks ago, and I don't know if this is due to a recent software update, or potentially related to a RAM upgrade from 16 to 32 GB. Would appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Screenshots:

[image: RAMMap overview]

[image: RAMMap breakdown]

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU Usgage**, **VirtualAlloc**, **ResidentSet** and click to start. Minimize the GUI and run it until you see the SYSTEM memory usage grow again. Now bring the Window back to front, click on Save to save the data into a ETL file. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll look at it and post what I see

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, here is the 7z: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwr2DsGD9yB6Wmp6MG9YeWdGcFE

Password is my username.

Comment: the tarce shows no memory allocation of the SYSTEM process. I can only see it has a size of 489MB, but this was done before you captured the trace. reboot and now run WPRUI and make sure you capture some of the usage **grow**. Otherwise nothing is included in the trace

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's strange. When that trace started the System process was at 60 MB, by the end it was around 500 MB.

Here's another trace upon fresh reboot, from ~60 to 600 MB. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwr2DsGD9yB6ZHVxalZ3SjI5QVE

I tried poking around WPA but am not very familiar with it and don't know where to look. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: the same. no memory allocation from SYSTEM process in the trace. The over 600MB were allocated before you started capturing the trace. I only see a lot of memory allocations from Chrome & firefox.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. You're totally right that the memory is already allocated -- it's because I am mounting a RAM disk via ImDisk at system startup. The memory is allocated but not committed until I start writing files there, which happens when I use Firefox / Chrome, which have their temp directories on the RAM disk. I just wish there were an easier way to have learned this conclusion.. http://reboot.pro/topic/15593-faqs-and-how-tos/ #6 goes into more detail

Anyway, thanks for the help! Did not know about WPR before.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in my situation..

This was ultimately traced to the use of imdisk for creating a virtual memory disk. As http://reboot.pro/topic/15593-faqs-and-how-tos/ #6 makes clear, the memory usage of the disk does not show up in the System process private working set until it is committed, when files are written to the disk. Furthermore, even as files are deleted from the disk the memory is not reclaimed because there is no way to decommit memory pages. Since I had put my system temp directory on the disk, the end effect was a gradually increasing System private working set as I used browsers that wrote files to the disk. And I only noticed the high System RAM usage because I had recently installed more RAM and dramatically increased the size of my RAM disk.

In retrospect, if I had used [Process Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HojyS.png) on the System process, it would have been immediately obvious that my 8G RAM disk was a prime suspect -- the System process private bytes is right at 8G.